# Link XSLT stylesheet without access to XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT stylesheet that is working just fine. I've been using a sample XML file of the type of file I will be using when this application goes live. I know that you can connect the stylesheet to the XML you are attempting to transform by inputting for example...

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
```

directly into the XML document. But what if I cannot make changes to the XML document I am trying to transform. It is automatically generated by a separate program and I cannot change it's contents. However, I would still like to be able to style the contents of the XML file using XSLT. Is there a way to accomplish this without including the statement I showed above?

Thanks.

Comment: How will users access the xml file?

Comment: I will access the XML file by syncing it will the XSLT in order display is on a webpage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "link" here. The stylesheet is an independent document; it is not normally aware of which input document it will be applied to, and in fact is usually applied to many. It sounds like what you mean is that you want to have your server apply the XSLT stylesheet to the XML before delivering the result to the user; is that correct?

Comment: @kesklam No that is not particularly correct. I am going to update my original question to explain in a little more detail. I am wanting to do the trasnformation on the client side. That is working no problem. However connecting the XSLT stylesheet requires that I add a <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="title.xsl"?> at the top of the XML I am attempting to transform. I would like to link the stylesheet to an XML file without having this statement linking the two.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want something like the opposite of `<xsl:output>`, but unfortunately that doesn't exist. `<xsl:import>` can only import stylesheets, not load XMLs.

To do the transformation on client side assuming a web application, you need to involve JavaScript, e.g. the [XSLT.JS library](http://johannburkard.de/software/xsltjs/).

If you have a C# client application, look for the [XsltCompiledTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xslt]+XsltCompiledTransform) class here on Stackoverflow.

As mentioned by *keshlam*, you might also try the [document()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms256465%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function. Especially example 3 of MSDN's website does not make use of additional JavaScript. I've never used it in the context of a web application, but might work.

Comment: XSLT's `document()` function can be used to explicitly load a specific source document as a nodeset, if that's really what you want.